# How do I make boot verbose in my Mac (i.e. Monterey) and also how can i see the specific boot log any time after (journalctl -k linux-like command)?

Tags: macos, startup, logs

I would like to:

- Know how to configure my MacBookPro (Monterey), to boot in verbose mode (see all the messages cascade).
- Know if there is an equivalent for `journalctl -k` in Mac. (I know that there is this application `Console` to see all logs, but i would like a command-line alternative).

In linux there is this command: `journalctl -k` that serves you a `less`-like interface where you can navigate through the boot log that just already happen and even you can explore previous boots (`journalctl -b`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For verbose mode use:

```
cmd+V
```

To set booting in verbose mode try:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
```

As for bootlog, in Terminal try:

```
sudo dmesg
```

With `sudo` you have to enter your password, unless you run as root (I don't run as root , I have my user account).

Comment: And what should be done to set verbose mode permanent? (And, by the way: how do i tag names like yours with a space between? ;) I tried @M... but didn't appear the autocomplete suggesting your name ((at)SolarMike neither (at)Solar Mike). How i can do that. Thanks!)

Comment: @nostromo - You can only tag someone who has already commented. An answer author will be flagged anyway. For Solar Mike, `@s` should generate the popup to choose from & automatically remove the space - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfGET.png